# How to reference an external file in sql?

Tags: sql

Probably quite a basic question, but I've had a look around on google, as well as on here, and can't find a great answer.

I am designing a database system to keep track of some date, including a selection of quite large data files. I realise it isn't usually seen as a good thing to include these datafiles in the database itself, but to refer to them somehow. The question is how.

Bearing in mind I am only in the design portion of the project now, and am very new to this. I'm designing it based on SQL, which I have never used before.

Comment: save url or file realpath, than open and read on program

Comment: What datatype should the file path be? Char? I only ask as it could potentially be quite long. If there a specific type?

Comment: only varchar(sizeOfUrl) Windows limits a single path to 260 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, the easiest way to do this is by storing the url or absolute filepath in the database.  This would allow you to access the files by retrieving that path using a query.

However, I think the best way to do it would be to hold a somewhat relative path in the database and then "filling in the rest" with the program that opens the file.  This makes it easier to test on your local machine and modify later.

For example,

You could have a FILE_PATH column in the database with paths such as "files/images/XXXX.jpg" and then use a variable like DATA_FILE_PATH in the program with the value "C://program_data/".  You would then concatenate these strings into "C://program_data/files/images/XXXX.jpg" which would be the complete path to the file.

This would allow you to change the path on the server without having to perform database surgery if you needed to move the files for some reason.  It's up to you how you do this, though!

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you should store the file names using and nvarchar() field of adequate length in some table.  The next step is to determine how you should then serve the files to some other application.